# Convert date from input to Date object

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, date, momentjs

I have input where I select date.

Here is code of input

```
<div class="input-group date" style="margin: 0 auto;padding-top: 20px;" id="picker">
    <input id="startAppointment" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Start Appointment" />
    <span style="width: 20px; height: 33px;" class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="color: #1d69b4;background:transparent !important;border:none;"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Here is code where I pass data to back-end

```
<script>
$('#save_appointment').click(function () {
    addAppointmentInternal();
});
function addAppointmentInternal() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Post',
        dataType: 'Json',
        data: {
            Start: $('#startAppointment').val(),
            End: $('#endAppointment').val(),
            Title: $('#title').val(),
            Date:$('#startAppointment').val(moment().toDate())
        },
        url: '@Url.Action("AddingInternalAppointment","Calendar")',
        success: function (da) {
            if (da.Result === "Success") {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                $("#myModal2").modal();
            } else {
                alert('Error' + da.Message);
            }
        },
        error: function(da) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
}
```

In back end I have this code

```
public ActionResult AddingInternalAppointment(string Start, string End, string Title)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;

        Appointment appointmentInt = new Appointment()
        {
            Start_appointment = Start,
            End_appointment = End,
            Title = Title,
            Type_of_appointment = "Internal",
            Date = dt
        };
        db.Appointments.Add(appointmentInt);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new { Result = "Success", Message = "Saved Successfully" });
    }
```

Now I add Date as Date object on back end, but I need to pass data from front-end and write it in this format `8/30/2017` in `date` format.

I tried to do this `Date:$('#startAppointment').val(moment().toDate())` , but it not works.

How I can do this?

Comment: `Date: moment($('#startAppointment').val()).toISOString()` so that its sent in ISO format and will always bind to `DateTime`

Comment: Will try now. Thank's@StephenMuecke

Comment: It works , thank's@StephenMuecke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have this action:

```
public ActionResult AddingInternalAppointment(string Start, string End, string Title, DateTime Date)
{
    ...
}
```

By using `Date: $('#startAppointment').val(moment().toDate())`, `startAppointment` element assigned with converted date from `moment` without converting to C# compatible `DateTime` format (still using JavaScript format, which will cause invalid value error). You need to use `val` from jQuery selector without any arguments & convert extracted value into `moment`-based format:

```
moment($('#startAppointment').val())
```

Then, adding `toISOString` method ensures the date value from `moment` processing converted & sent in UTC format, which recognized by `DateTime` argument during AJAX call:

```
Date: moment($('#startAppointment').val()).toISOString()
```

Afterwards, you can convert submitted date to American date format for display by using `ToString` or `String.Format`.